# Intrinsic glitch of an XOR port

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, delay, port

I'm dealing with a glitch of an XOR gate. I read in the book *Code Design for Dependable Systems: Theory and Practical Applications* that a glitch is generated when more than one input variable is changed simultaneously, due to the structure of the port (i.e. in a 2-input XOR port, when the 2 inputs change simultaneously, for example from 00 to 11). I would like to understand the reason why the transistors -arranged like in the following image- lead to this behaviour:

[image: Cmos_xor.svg]

Comment: Step 1: Imagine all transistors stable with a "11" input. Step 2: realise (the book should have mentioned that before this subject...) every transistor takes time to propagate the effect of a changed gate (input) to its drain-source junction (output). Step 3: Now make a table with columns for each "transition time" and note down the levels of all the signals if the inputs go to "00" exactly at t=0. If you need real-world numbers, feel free to imagine a transition is 1ns, 1us, 1ms or 1s, because it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think i understood that, while T6,T10 turn  on i have T5,T9 still on and so my pull-up network is activated.
But on the opposite condition? If i have a stable 00 input and they switch both to 11? I cannot see how I can get an output intermediate transition to 1

Answer (score 1):

The glitch has nothing to do with the XOR gate and with this particular implementation. You can get glitches with almost any circuitry when two or more signals switch at the same time. In reality the signals never switch exactly at the same time. Whether you get the glitch or not, and how long is it depends on delays of the actual circuit, and that depends on the manufacturing deviations, temperature, supply voltage, phase of the Moon and so on.

If the glitch is a problem, use clock synchronous circuits, and when crossing clock domains make sure that only one signal is switching at a time. That can be ensured by using Gray code counters, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yor're right. There's something wrong with the circuit at all:

If you start from 00 and switch to 11 you see:

```
  T5, T9, T11, T12 are close => LOW
  T6, T7, T8,  T10 close within T_on
```

but the inverted inputs propagate also delayed by T_on!!!

```
   so T5, T9, T11, T12 open delayed (T_on + T_off)
while T6, T7, T8,  T10 close delayed by T_on
```

so for the duration of T_off you do not have a glitch but a short circuit.